# Assignment to part of a multi-dimentional array in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I want to change some of the elements in an array, but can figure out how to do it.

This line: `sig3(1) <= (11, 12);` gives me an error

```
entity t1 is
end entity;

architecture testbench of t1 is

    type type3 is array(1 to 2, 1 to 2) of integer;

    signal sig3 : type3;

begin
    process is
    begin
        -- sig3 <= ((11, 12), (13, 14));  -- this works
        sig3(1) <= (11, 12);   -- get error:  "Incompatible types for assignment."
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have defined the array unfortunately precludes the method you favour of assigning:
If you decalre a type like this:

```
type type3 is array(1 to 2, 1 to 2) of integer;
signal sig3 : type3;
```

Assignments have to fully specify the index:

```
sig3(1,1) <= 11;
sig3(1,2) <= 12;
```

You can define a 2d array as a array of 1-d arrays though

```
type type4 is array(1 to 2) of integer;
type type5 is array(1 to 2) of type4;
signal sig5 : type5;
```

You can now assign it like this:

```
sig5(1) <= (11,12);
```

Unfortunately, you can't work so easily in the other dimension.